# Error multiple params in the expression "in"

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Crystal Reports XI
I have this script which contains two parameters - {Location Name} and {Provider}

```
    insert @pat_tracking(person_id, last_name, first_name, dob, 
    mrn, enc_id, enc_nbr, enc_timestamp, enc_date, 
    provider, attending_ind, location, time1)
select distinct p.person_id, p.last_name, p.first_name, CONVERT(date, p.date_of_birth, 112), 
    convert(int, pa.med_rec_nbr), pe.enc_id, pe.enc_nbr, pe.create_timestamp, CONVERT(date, pe.create_timestamp), 
    pm.description, ppm.attending_ind, lm.location_name, convert(datetime, CONVERT(time, pe.create_timestamp))
from person p
    join patient_encounter pe on p.person_id=pe.person_id
    join patient pa on p.person_id=pa.person_id and pe.practice_id=pa.practice_id
    join provider_mstr pm on pe.rendering_provider_id=pm.provider_id
    join provider_practice_mstr ppm on pe.practice_id=ppm.practice_id and pm.provider_id=ppm.provider_id
    join location_mstr lm on pe.location_id=lm.location_id
    join pat_apt_status_hx_ pash on pe.enc_id=pash.enc_id
where
 lm.location_name in {?Location Name}
and  convert(varchar(36), pe.rendering_provider_id) in {?Provider}
```

But, when I save this  - I get error:
"Failed to retrieve data from DB... Incorrect syntax.."
These are params contain multiple choice  - one or more items.
What can I do  to fix that error? 
Thanks all and best regards

Comment: check whether the `{?Provider}` is defined as `Single` or `Multiple`... If it is single then change to `Multiple` and check.

Comment: Do You mean the Allow Multiple Values? - It is set TRUE

Comment: That error message is awfully ambiguous; what makes you think it is due to your parameters?

Comment: Because without parameters works fine. This is a bug that particular version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Thank you all for participating - the problem of the bugs CR. new version of СR - isn't problem